# Is there a better way to form this code example?

Tags: promise, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I'm new to rxjs and using redux-observable.  The short of it is that I need to make a couple promise requests when i get a connection then output the results.  I'm wondering if there is a way to join this into a single map at the end and not have to call store.dispatch multiple times and have the retry work for each individual read.  Thanks ahead of time for your comments.

```
export const handleBleConnectionSuccess = (action$,store,{bleCommunicator}) =>
  action$.ofType(c.BLE_CONNECTION_SUCCESS)
    .do((a)=>{
      Observable.fromPromise(bleCommunicator.readCharacteristic(a.device.id,gattInfo.uuid,gattInfo.firmwareRevision.uuid))
        .do((value)=>store.dispatch({type:c.DEVICE_FIRMWARE_VERSION,device:{...a.device,firmwareVersion:value}}))
        .retry(3);

      Observable.fromPromise(bleCommunicator.readCharacteristic(a.device.id,gattInfo.uuid,gattInfo.modelNumber.uuid))
        .do(value=>store.dispatch({type:c.DEVICE_MODEL_NUMBER,device:{...a.device,modelNumber:value}}))
        .retry(3);
    })
    .mapTo({type:'DEVICE_INFORMATION_REQUESTED'});
```

Comment: it really depends on whether the state update side effect is really needed or to be in order, more I use rxjs more I find redux not too useful

Comment: I do needful the results from the two calls to read that but don't really need the mapto device info requested.

Comment: Your pattern is already making sense and straight forward, can consider use forkjoin and have on result array at the end https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to join this into a single map at the end and not have to call store.dispatch multiple times and have the retry work for each individual read

Yes, there is a better way, and it's possible to do what you want.
From the syntax, I'm guessing that you use ngrx (effects) (and not redux-observable).

So with ngrx/effects you could do it like that:

```
export const handleBleConnectionSuccess = (
  action$,
  store,
  { bleCommunicator }
) =>
  action$.ofType(c.BLE_CONNECTION_SUCCESS).switchMap(a => {
    const readCharacteristic = deviceOrFirmwareUuid =>
      bleCommunicator.readCharacteristic(a.device.id, gattInfo.uuid, deviceOrFirmwareUuid);

    return Observable.merge(
      readCharacteristic(gattInfo.firmwareRevision.uuid)
        .map(value => ({
          type: c.DEVICE_FIRMWARE_VERSION,
          device: { ...a.device, firmwareVersion: value },
        }))
        .retry(3),

      readCharacteristic(gattInfo.modelNumber.uuid)
        .map(value => ({
          type: c.DEVICE_MODEL_NUMBER,
          device: { ...a.device, modelNumber: value },
        }))
        .retry(3),

      { type: 'DEVICE_INFORMATION_REQUESTED' }
    );
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but I am in fact using redux observable epics and rxjs5. I'll look to see if merge will handle promises because read characteristic returns one.

Comment: Yes most operators can directly handle promises ;)

Comment: Inside your epics (aka effects, in ngrx) there is nearly no difference between redux-observable and ngrx/effects because it's just idiomatic RxJS where you happen to be working with actions. We both provide an identical `ofType` operator as well to make this easier.